# I want to classify two types of data, how to apply machine learning classifier algorithm in this type of datasets

Tags: machine-learning, classification

I have to classify some points into two class either 0 or 1. Which ml algorithm is suitable I need some genuine suggestion.

I tried to apply logistic regression, but couldn't succeed.

I want one class for yellow dots and anther for purple dots.

I want to get two class data

[image: image 1]

Comment: could you please explain further your dataset? As long as I can see from the chart, each sample has 2 features, x and y. Is it correct?

Comment: my dataset has three features like x,y, and w, the value of x and y is either 0 or 1. the value of w is plotted with x in the figure. what I need is to classify these purple and yellow color points into two class. these colors depend on the value of y. if 1 then yellow if 0 then 1.

Comment: Use a RandomForest Classifier.

Answer (score 0):

You can use logistic regression which uses a sigmoid function to determine the probabilities of the output. Now you can set threshold(usually 0.5) to classify the data using a simple if check.

```
   if(x[I]>=0.5)
     y[I]==1
   else 
     y[I]==0
```